# How to retreive a related object field?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How can i retreive a related object with ampscript? I read the whole forum and looked it up in Google but i can't get it to work.

I tried this but it returns the error: An unrecognized expression appears in a script block.

```
%%[
    Var @field
    Set @field = Placement__c_Salesforce:Vessel_Rig_Platform__r:name

]%%


%%=V(@field)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [RetreiveSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)s Ampscript call and parse it with the Rows call.

Assuming you are searching the lead object (If its a custom object, change the value accoridngly)

```
eg
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Placement__c_Salesforce', 'Vessel_Rig_Platform__r', '=', @QueryValue)


IF NOT Empty(@rs) THEN 
    Set @row = ROW(@rs,1)
    Set @QueryValue = FIELD(@row,"Placement_c_Salesforce")
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@QueryValue)=%%
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Data_Kid, i am quite new to AMPscript and eager to learn. Can you please provide the AMPscript?

Comment: I have provided a code snippet and a link to the documentation to assit @wfrankhuizen

Comment: Sorry but the code isn't working. I need the Placement__c_Salesforce:Vessel_Rig_Platform__r:name and in your code i doesn't refer to that.

Comment: please refrain from asking for working (copy pasteable) code samples,  instead, go through the documenttion, do trailhead(s), and keep trying. Open new posts with specific problems related to your code instead of opening How To questions. Thanks!

Comment: I did all the trailheads and read all documentation about the functions. Because i am a complete beginner i need to understand how i can return related objects with RetreiveSalesforceObjects. I can't find it anywhere and did a few hours of testing already.